# How do I add the UAC shield icon to the standard messagebox?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-xp

I want to notify the user that my application wants to start an elevated process using the standard `MessageBox`. Is there a way of achieving this short of reimplementing the `MessageBox`?

For example, for standard buttons, you can send the `BCM_SETSHIELD` message. Is there something similar for message boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buttons in a message dialog are standard buttons, you can send them a `BCM_SETSHIELD` message.

For this, you need to be aware when a message dialog box is activated. One way can be to set a temporary [`WH_CBT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hook and in its [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) watch for an 'nCode' of `HCBT_ACTIVATE` for a window having the dialog class (#32770).

Another way can be to handle [`WM_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after 'MessageBox' is called, 'wParam' should be `WA_ACTIVE` and 'lParam' should be a window handle again of the dialog class. Then you can send the 'BCM_SETSHIELD' message to the button f.i. having control id `IDOK`.

[image: messsage box with shielded button]

Comment: +1 Good work, but I feel my solution is a little less hacky!!

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is as close as I'll get to what I want. I will investigate this a little further.

Comment: @David - Thanks!.. Not very much I guess, #32770 is `WC_DIALOG` in winuser.h. class names are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system), even if for *completeness sake*. :)

Comment: I guess it's not so hacky if you are comfortable with message hooking. I'm not, but that's just lack of experience. You got the tick though, so I have to give best to you on this one!  ;-)

Answer (score 10):

In order to get the shield icon onto the buttons of a system provided message dialog you are going to need to handle a callback from the dialog.

For example, I will illustrate with the [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28VS.85%29.aspx) API introduced in Vista.

The basic dialog allows you to specify the main icon, but not the shield icon for the buttons on the dialog.  To do this you need to provide a [callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that responds to the `TDN_CREATED` notification.

That callback might look like this:

```
HRESULT CALLBACK TaskDialogCallbackProc(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uNotification,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam,
    LONG_PTR dwRefData
)
{
   if (TDN_CREATED == uNotification)
   {
       SendMessage(
           hwnd,
           TDM_SET_BUTTON_ELEVATION_REQUIRED_STATE,
           ID_FOR_MY_BUTTON_SPECIFIED_IN_TASKDIALOGCONFIG_STRUCT,
           1
       );
   }
   return S_OK;
}
```

The magic is contained in the [`TDM_SET_BUTTON_ELEVATION_REQUIRED_STATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787511%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

As far as I can tell, this is the way you are intended to achieve the effect you desire.

Comment: This looks great, but I'm still targeting XP. So no vista APIs for me... I should maybe add an XP tag.

Comment: XP doesn't have UAC and so trying to show the shield icon will have no effect. Sertac's hacks could break on a future version of Windows. My recommendation would be to invest a little more time into implementing a wrapper class that called MessageDialog on XP, and TaskDialogIndirect on Vista and above.